# Update Github "Releases" text from API

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a way to automatically update the "Releases" version number on a Github page? Either from automatic machinery within Github, or using some API to update it?

(See the release number "3.5.0" in the image below...) Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sidebar component shows you the latest release (I believe).  If you want to add a release, that can be done [using the REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-release).  You can also update the release using the REST API.

Note that it isn't sufficient to just push a tag here.  A release on GitHub is associated with a tag, but it can also have a message and assets (usually binaries or source code) associated with it.  You do need such a tag, but you also need to create the actual release on GitHub.

If you want an example of how this can be done with shell scripting, Git LFS [has a script that performs this task](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/script/upload) as part of the release process.